# md-datepicker date filter: Send object from HTML to md-date-filter function

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, material-design

I'm creating a tour booking system in AngularJS with Material Design.

The tours are generated into the DOM with `ng-repeat`. Every `tour` object contains information about on which dates this tour should be available. I need to send the `tour` object containing this information to the md-date-filter function, but I don't know how to do it.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="tour in tours">
    <md-datepicker
        ng-model="tour.group.selectedDate"
        md-min-date="booking.visit.dateStart"
        md-max-date="booking.visit.dateEnd"
        md-date-filter="disableDepDates"
    ></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

This is the date filter function:

```
$scope.disableDepDates = function(date) {
    console.log(date);

    //Check date here and return true if date is ok
};
```

The problem is that whenever I do `md-date-filter="disableDepDates(tour)"` in the HTML, the `date` filter object gets lost.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I've also noted that when I use `md-date-filter="disableDepDates(tour)"`, the `disableDepDates()` function will run spontaneously at page load, whenever I focus on any form element etc. By default, `md-date-filter` will be a function as stated here:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker

Comment: what is the result from the console.log?

Comment: There is no message to the console log unfortunately. I've been trying to find some useful information using `this`, but I haven't been able to find the date object there when using `md-date-filter="disableDepDates"`, or the parent model `tour` when using `md-date-filter="disableDepDates(tour)"`.

Comment: Have you injected "ngMaterial" into your Controller?

Comment: Yes, right here: `var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngAnimate","ngMessages","ngMaterial","ngMaterialDateRangePicker"]);`. The whole site uses Material Design, and everything else works perfectly fine.

Comment: I noticed in your EDIT that the function will run when you use it like that. So, I think it should work by taking the date input in the function and make it go into some conditions that whether this date is valid for your application and return boolean at the end of the function indicating that this input date is valid or not. So that it will disable accordingly in the date picker.

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from md-datepicker is that you are already limiting the dates between min and max. the md-date-filter will be used to add filter using a comparison so it will evaluate every available date in the calendar (every day of the current visual month that passes min and max) and will expect a return to disable the availability of that day or not.
lets say we have this

```
<md-datepicker
        ng-model="2019-05-06"
        md-min-date="2019-04-01"
        md-max-date="2019-05-15"
        md-date-filter="disableDepDates"
    ></md-datepicker>
```

and we only have ['2019-04-05','2019-04-06', '2019-05-06', '2019-05-10'] available
so in the script we should have something like

```
$scope.disableDepDates = function(date) {
var day = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + date.getMonth()).substr(-2) + '-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).substr(-2);
if(['2019-04-05','2019-04-06', '2019-05-06', '2019-05-10'].indexOf(day)!=-1)
 return day;
};
});
```